# Issues reading a characteristic from a paired BLE device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Using CoreBluetooth on iOS(10.3) i'm unable to read a characteristics value when bonded(paired?) to a custom BLE HID Device.  If I remain unbonded I can read the characteristic fine.

The BLE device implements HID over GATT(HOGP) and an additional service with a single notify characteristic.  This additional service/characteristic is what I'm trying to read, not the HID over GATT data which I know is filtered out.

It appears that didDiscoverServices never gets called. I do see didConnect being called.

I'm able to accomplish this on Android so I don't think it's an issue with the BLE device.

Relevant code below:

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    var showAlert = true
    var message = ""

    switch central.state {
    case .poweredOff:
        message = NSLocalizedString("Bluetooth on this device is currently powered off.", comment: "")
    case .unsupported:
        message = NSLocalizedString("This device does not support Bluetooth Low Energy.", comment: "")
    case .unauthorized:
        message = NSLocalizedString("This app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy.", comment: "")
    case .resetting:
        message = NSLocalizedString("The BLE Manager is resetting; a state update is pending.", comment: "")
    case .unknown:
        message = NSLocalizedString("The state of the BLE Manager is unknown.", comment: "")
    case .poweredOn:
        showAlert = false
        message = NSLocalizedString("Bluetooth LE is turned on and ready for communication.", comment: "")

        let lastPeripherals = centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(string: Device.DeviceServiceUUID)])

        print("count: \(lastPeripherals.count)")
        if lastPeripherals.count > 0{
            let device = lastPeripherals.last!;
            connectingPeripheral = device;
            centralManager.connect(connectingPeripheral, options: nil)
        } else {
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(string: "7340")], options: nil)
        }

    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    if let peripheralName = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String {
        if peripheralName == deviceName {

            // save a reference to the device
            device= peripheral
            device!.delegate = self

            // Request a connection to the peripheral
            centralManager.connect(device!, options: nil)
        }
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {

}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("****** DISCONNECTION DETAILS: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    }
    device = nil
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("ERROR DISCOVERING SERVICES: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    if let services = peripheral.services {
        for service in services {
            print("DISCOVERED SERVICE: \(service)")
            if (service.uuid == CBUUID(string: Device.DeviceServiceUUID)) {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }
        }
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("ERROR DISCOVERING CHARACTERISTICS: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    if let characteristics = service.characteristics {

        for characteristic in characteristics {
            // Message Data Characteristic
            if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: Device.MessageCharacteristicUUID) {
                // Enable the message notifications
                messageCharacteristic = characteristic
                device?.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            }


        }
    }
}


func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("ERROR ON UPDATING VALUE FOR CHARACTERISTIC: \(characteristic) - \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    // extract the data from the characteristic's value property and display the value based on the characteristic type
    if let dataBytes = characteristic.value {
        if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: Device.MessageCharacteristicUUID) {
            displayMessage(dataBytes)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did didConnect get called?

Comment: didConnect is called

Comment: are you using pairing or bonding on your peripheral?

Comment: It is paired as it acts as a keyboard.

Comment: So I reread the HOGP spec and it appears to actually be bonding not pairing.

Comment: What is the peripheral? Is the peripheral still sending advertisements after bonding or does is stop?

Comment: @KeithConger Did you ever figure this out? I'm also developing a hardware device that acts as a HID controller but should also provide normal BLE services and characteristics.